# Quadratic equation -

Tags: quadratics

I have been struggling with this quadratic equation question quite a bit. 
Specify the zero points for the following function and the coordinates of the parabol peak.

$$g(x)=4x^2 +36$$

Edit 1 - this is where I got stuck: $$g(x)=4(x^2+9)$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @JamesLeaf: What if you wrote it as $$g(x) = 4 \left(x^2+9\right)$$ **Hint:** you get two complex conjugate imaginary roots.

Comment: Yeah i actually did that, but that is where i got stuck.

Comment: Didn't you set it equal to zero?

Comment: What you call a peak looks very much like a glen…

Comment: *WHY* did you get stuck.  What happened when you tried?  Be specific.  (Hint:  Why do you think this this has a solution?)

Comment: I actually thought this had an answer, but i think i got it now as someone answerd to my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

To find the zero set

$$g(x)=4x^2 +36=0\implies x^2=-\frac{36}4=-9 $$

thus we don't have real solution, that means we don't have real roots for $g$.

For the peak let consider

$$g'(x)=8x=0\implies x=0$$

thus the peak is $g(0)=36$ which of course is a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $\;x^2+9\ge 9$ if $x$ is real.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know calculus, you can derive the maximum or minimum of a quadratic $$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$ by looking at it in vertex form: $$f(x)=a(x-h)^2+k,$$ where $h=\frac{-b}{2}$ and so $f(h)=k$ is the maximum or minimum value of this function, since it is the unique point which lies on the axis of symmetry.